# Duplicate the if result in foreach

Tags: php

In short, I'm downloading from the category_id, product_id, and active activity tag. The idea is that like all products assigned to a particular category_id have a value of 0, I display the echo "empty", otherwise "products contains", but the foreach loop instead passes through the product id and displays empty + category_id once, passes through $ status and displays So many echo, how many records are active.

The query is ok - I know I should not perform logical operations on arrays, but the database is structured so that I have no output.

```
$result = array();

            foreach ($products as $detail) {

                $cid = $detail['category_id'];
                $pid = $detail['product_id'];
                $status = $detail['active'];
                $result[$cid][$pid] = $status;

                $multiplier = $result[$cid][$pid];
                $counter = count($result[$cid]);
                $multiplier2 = 1;


                $multiplier = $multiplier * $multiplier2;
                echo '$status: ' .$multiplier. " | ";

                if ($multiplier == 0) {
                    echo '$cid: '.$cid.' | empty <br />';
                } else {
                    echo '$cid: '.$cid.' | products contains <br />';
                }

            }
```

Duplicate cause, but I do not know how to change the code in this code

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [category_id] => 221
            [1] => 221
            [active] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [category_id] => 221
            [1] => 221
            [active] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )
)
```

$result array

```
Array
(
    [221] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )
)
```

@EDIT

Currently, the function returns something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrSfu.png)

And based on this array, it should be something like - as you can see 1437 has => 1 so the category is not empty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek3BL.png)

Comment: Can you please do a better job explaining what you are doing and what you want to achieve? Maybe include current outputted data and what it should look like.

Comment: I added some information, enough?

Comment: Could you provide the sample input array that becomes your current output?

Comment: The second code from the top is the table that I receive directly after downloading the products from the database

Comment: So how can you save it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to isolate what is and is not empty from a scattered list (it does sound like you might be able to do a better query though). See if this iteration helps filter.

```
function getCategoryActivity($products)
    {
        $store = array();
        foreach($products as $detail) {
            $cid = $detail['category_id'];
            $pid = $detail['product_id'];
            # If the cid is not already stored, store it
            if(!isset($store[$cid]))
                $store[$cid] = $detail['active'];
            else {
                # If it's already set to active, ignore it
                if(!empty($store[$cid]))
                    continue;
                else
                    # Store it if not currently active
                    $store[$cid] = $detail['active'];
            }
        }
        # Send back the filtered array
        return $store;
    }
# Fetch the filtered array
$sorted = getCategoryActivity($products);
```

`$sorted` should give you a list of categories now that have activity in them and not in them. You can iterate one more time using `array_map()` or another `foreach()` to `echo` what you want. I have no idea what you are trying to do with that multiplier part so I ignored it.